# How to save a copy of a Batch file after cutting out some parts of it?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I created a batch file which schedules itself to run on logon, *(in Task Scheduler)*, and which includes code to run some VBScripts, which show some msgboxes.

I want to avoid the batch file from showing the msgbox at scheduled run time only, the msgbox should be shown when the script is run via any other method.

I Tried doing this;

```bash
echo @echo off >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\script.bat
echo IF EXIST "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\script.vbs" goto :del >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\script.bat
echo set value=%value:~0,-1% >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\script.bat
echo if %var%==123 set var1=1234 >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\script.bat
echo exit >> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\script.bat
```

I tried exporting the code without the msgboxes to another batch file located in `%temp%` dir, but the code fails because I have a code like `set value=%value:~0,-1%` which doesn't get echoed into the other batch file, but it executes as a normal line of code instead.

If there is another way of doing this, please let me know.

Comment: Instead of trying to figure out WHO is executing it (e.g., the task scheduler or a human user), why not tailor HOW it's executed? I.e., pass in a parameter when the scheduler executes your batch file, and fork your logic based on whether that parameter is provided. Also, you should supply some semi-realistic code if you want people to make recommendations. 3 `echo` statements give little sense of your actual scenario.

Comment: if some code is provided on how to find 'how its executed' its highly appreciated

Comment: Realistic code is highly appreciated? I concur :) Command line parameters are accessible by `%1`, `%2`, etc. Executing `mycommand.bat task_scheduler` passes "task_scheduler" into `%1`, which you can do `if` logic on.

Comment: Perhaps you should `echo` ```%%value:~0,-1%%``` and ```%%var%%``` instead.

Comment: Ok, it could work, ill try it out and let you know... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method may be to add a parameter to the scheduled version (like `/scheduled` for instance) and look for that parameter within the batch.

Bonus! You can test the difference by running `whateveryourbatchis /scheduled` to test the scheduled version without actually scheduling it (permissions considerations aside)